# Configuring TigerVNC systemd process on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, vnc

I've been trying to get TigerVNC working on a clean install of desktop Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME and all). Running `vncserver :1 -localhost no` allows me to connect perfectly fine, but my systemd service does not seem to work.

Log after system boot:

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.7.0 - built Dec  5 2017 09:25:01
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11905000, The X.Org Foundation


Wed Jul 10 15:13:27 2019
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
vncconfig: unable to open display ":1"

** (process:1184): WARNING **: 15:13:28.311: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

Log after starting the vncserver manually in terminal (`vncserver :1 -localhost no`):

```
Xvnc TigerVNC 1.7.0 - built Dec  5 2017 09:25:01
Copyright (C) 1999-2016 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11905000, The X.Org Foundation


Wed Jul 10 15:14:25 2019
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":1"
      after 175 requests (174 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
vncconfig -iconic & dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

vncserver@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=TigerVNC Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=<user>
PAMName=login

PIDFile=/home/<user>/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :%i -localhost no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Was running into the same error, even when just running from the command line.  Adding your `xstartup` content fixed it.  Thanks for making a good question @joona!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial and error, I decided to just run the process in user mode, after user has logged in. Service starts after user logs in, and with auto-login enabled it works perfectly fine for my purpose.

I removed `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service` file and created a new one in `$HOME/.local/share/systemd/user/vncserver@.service` with the following contents (and created the missing folders).

vncserver@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=TigerVNC Service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver :%i -localhost no
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Then I enabled the service with `systemctl daemon-reload --user` and enabled it with `systemctl enable vncserver@1 --user`.

Answer (score 3):

I was not able to get it to work with the SystemD 'User=' line, evan with the PAMName line.

After some trial and error, I was able to get the following to work. I had to use 'su'  but it works nonetheless.
Note: you will need to replace username with your linux username. For newbies setting up tigervnc, you will also have to had created a vncpasswd already for this user. To do so just run vncpasswd in a shell under the username before starting the service or rebooting the system. 

Save as: /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=TigerVNC Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
SuccessExitStatus=0

PIDFile=/home/username/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=/bin/su -l username -c "/usr/bin/tigervncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null"
ExecStart=/bin/su -l username -c "/usr/bin/tigervncserver :%i -localhost no"
ExecStop=/bin/su -l username -c "/usr/bin/tigervncserver -kill :%i"

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: +1 This is the only one that worked for me. I tried many others, including templates from tutorials by DigitalOcean, Teknotut, etc.

Comment: +1 great solution. I wrote about this solution here: https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/684, where I found some others using an local SSH session as a workaround, but this is a far more optimized solution that doesn't have any unnecessary layers of complexity added to it

Answer (score 2):

The [workaround with su](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611494/436311) found by Paul Richards is the best solution so far to start TigerVNC as a service on Ubuntu 18.04.

To get an Ubuntu desktop (instead of a Gnome one) edit ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

vncconfig −nowin &
dbus-launch --exit-with-session env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu gnome-session --session=ubuntu &
```

Comment: Thanks for the xstartup edit, which gave me a partial solution of this strange problem: I get a VNC session just fine by entering `vncserver` into Terminal of the server machine. But if I use systemd or `vncsever` "over SSH" (SSH into the server machine and use the command), then I get a defective VNC desktop. When xstartup was set to Gnome, the defects were (a) missing Dock, (b) missing "maximize" and "minimize" buttons, and (c) themes (colors etc. on apps) other than I set. Using Ubuntu, per your edit, gave me back the Dock. Any idea how I might fix (b) and (c) too? On Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks!